# Unable to upload file using c# WebClient and php FILES

Tags: c#, php, file-upload

The following C# code is used to upload the json file (~3.6 MB) to the server. Here, I am using WebClient to upload file to the server.

```
 private void btnUploadToServer_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
                {
                    string filePath = @"C:\Users\SAKTHY-PC\Desktop\app_erp_suneka.json";
                    var serverPath = new Uri(@"http://example.com/newSync/upload.php");
                    client.UploadFile(myUri,filePath);
                }

                   Application.Exit();
            }
            catch (Exception err)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(err.Message);
            }
        }
```

And I have a php script file (`upload.php`) in the following folder `http://example.com/newSync/`

```
<?php
    $filepath = $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
    move_uploaded_file($filepath,"app_erp_suneka.json");
?>
```

The problem is unable to upload 2MB or more than 2MB file to the server. But less than 2MB file is successfully uploaded.

Comment: What's the error message when uploading a file that is bigger than 2MB?

Comment: No error messages in C# and no log file in server also. When I click the upload button, bit time after the Application closes.

Comment: Try setting the Application.Exit(); after the try/catch block.

Comment: I put as you suggested but the program works some time as busy then closes. No error messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check and increase theese variables on your PHP server (php.ini file):

```
post_max_size => 8M
upload_max_filesize => 2M
```

Check it in phpinfo() or in server console:

```
php --info | grep upload_max_filesize
php --info | grep post_max_size
php --info | grep php.ini <-- shows where php.ini is
```

And control your php-log -- all errors and warnings are shown here:

```
php --info | grep error_log <-- where error_log is
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I only change the `upload_max_filesize =>` from `2M` to `16M`. Now it works perfectly.